# How to prevent the "Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode" from setState method

Tags: reactjs, setstate

This is my code:

```
import Card  from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Collapse from 'react-bootstrap/Collapse';
import React from 'react';
import MuteButton from './buttons/muteButton/MuteButton';
import PInPButton from "./buttons/pInPButton/PInPButton";
import Utility from '../../Utility';
import './MediaPlayer.css'
class MediaPlayer extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.playerOverlay =React.createRef();
        this.videoTag = React.createRef();
        this.state={ muted:true, elapseTime:"00:00:00",showControlBar:true};
        this.setCurrentTime=((currentTime)=>{
            this.videoTag.current.currentTime=currentTime;
        });
        this.setStream=((stream)=>{
            this.videoTag.srcObject=null;
            this.videoTag.srcObject=stream;
        });
       
    }
    toggleControlBar=(obj)=>{
            
    };
    toggleMute = () => {
        this.setState({
          muted: !this.state.muted
        });
    };
    togglePInP=(()=>{

    })    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.videoTag.ontimeupdate=(()=>{
            var result=Utility.toHHMMSS(this.videoTag.currentTime);
            this.setState({"elapseTime":result});
        });
        
        this.playerOverlay.onclick=((event)=>{
            if (event.target.classList.contains("playerOverlay")){
                this.setState((state) => ({
                    showControlBar: !state.showControlBar
                }));
                //this.setState({showControlBar:!this.state.showControlBar});
            }
        });        
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Card className="h-100 rounded">
                <video 
                    autoPlay 
                    muted={this.state.muted}
                    className="card-body p-0 rounded w-100"
                    ref={(instance) => (this.videoTag = instance)}>
                        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
                <div 
                    className="align-items-center 
                        justify-content-center 
                        playerOverlay
                        text-white"
                        >
               </div>
                <div className="p-1 
                                justify-content-end 
                                playerOverlay
                                rounded"
                    ref={(instance) => (this.playerOverlay = instance)}>
                  <Collapse in={this.state.showControlBar} 
                    className="bg-secondary p-1 rounded text-white w-100 ">
                    <div className="p-0 m-0">
                        <div className="align-items-center d-flex flex-row justify-content-between p-0">
                            <MuteButton toggleMute={this.toggleMute}  muted={this.state.muted}/>
                            <div><span>{this.state.elapseTime}</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="align-items-center d-flex flex-row justify-content-between p-0">
                            <PInPButton togglePInP={this.togglePInP}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </Collapse>
                </div>    
            </Card>     
        );
    }    
}
export default MediaPlayer;
```

The problem is that when the following event handler is executed,

```
this.playerOverlay.onclick=((event)=>{
        if (event.target.classList.contains("playerOverlay")){
            this.setState((state) => ({
                showControlBar: !state.showControlBar
            }));
            //this.setState({showControlBar:!this.state.showControlBar});
        }
    });
```

The following warning message is shown in the console:

```
index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode.
```

I found that the "this.setState" function caused the error.

I have tried to modify the above code to remove the warning, however, it does not work.

I have followed [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage) to change the below coding:

```
ref={(instance) => (this.playerOverlay = instance)}>
```

to

```
 ref={this.playerOverlay}>
```

However, still no luck.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`findDOMNode` is deprecated in `StrictMode`. Its usage is discouraged and, possibly, it will be deleted in a future version. Still, there are ways to overcome this with alternatives.

Of course, we should not remove the `StrictMode` as it may introduce other potential issues.

1. Add DOM node wrapper

```
...
componentDidMount() {
      const node = this.wrapper.current;
      /* Uses DOM node  */ 
}
wrapper = React.createRef();

render(){
 ...
  <div ref={this.wrapper}>
     ...
  </div>
 ...
}
```

2. [Ref forwading](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components)

Wrap child component in `React.forwardRef(props,ref)`

```js
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  <div ref={ref}>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

3. Using HOC(Higher Order components)

Here are a couple of posts that maybe useful for this.

https://medium.com/trabe/getting-rid-of-finddomnode-method-in-your-react-application-a0d7093b2660

https://medium.com/trabe/a-better-way-of-using-refs-in-react-dd970d2b13e5

Answer (score 0):

According to Pramod, you only need to create a new childComponent with react.forwardRef passing respective props and refs:

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  <div ref={ref}>
    <yourChildcomponent {...props} />
  </div>
```

In your render change the name of the original Child for the new:

```
<ChildCompoent... />
```